# how to get name of a file in directory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, file

There is an mkv file in a folder named "`export`". What I want to do is to make a python script which fetches the file name from that export folder.
Let's say the folder is at "`C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\New_folder\export`".

How do I fetch the name?

I tried using this `os.path.basename` and `os.path.splitext` .. well.. didn't work out like I expected.

Comment: Why didn't `os.path.basename` work? Can you show an example code in which it didn't work?

Comment: Can you paste your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
from glob import glob

pth ="C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/New_folder/export/"
print(glob(pth+"*.mkv"))
```

`path+"*.mkv"` will match all the files ending with `.mkv`.

To just get the basenames you can use map or a list comp with iglob:

```
from glob import iglob

print(list(map(path.basename,iglob(pth+"*.mkv"))))


print([path.basename(f) for f in  iglob(pth+"*.mkv")])
```

iglob returns an iterator so you don't build a list for no reason.

Comment: Thank you. I'm use your code like this => 
    def list_images(input_dir):
        return list(map(os.path.abspath, iglob(input_dir + "\\" + "*.jpg")))

Answer (score 13):

[`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) implements some useful functions on pathnames. But it doesn't have access to the contents of the path. For that purpose, you can use `os.listdir`.

The following command will give you a list of the contents of the given path:

```
os.listdir("C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\New_folder\export")
```

Now, if you just want `.mkv` files you can use [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)(*This module provides support for Unix shell-style wildcards*) module to get your expected file names:

```
import fnmatch
import os

print([f for f in os.listdir("C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\New_folder\export") if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.mkv')])
```

Also as @Padraic Cunningham mentioned as a more pythonic way for dealing with file names you can use `glob` module :

```
map(path.basename,glob.iglob(pth+"*.mkv"))
```

Comment: if you were going to use os.listdir, `if f.endswith(".mkv")` would be sufficient

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah there are some ways for this task but as you can see in https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html and also since it used Unix shell-style wildcards I think its more pythonic and faster than other ways! what you think?

Comment: `map(path.basename,iglob(pth+"*.mkv"))` will be faster and more memory efficient

Comment: .endswith is also faster

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah I this its so If you’re just trying to
provide a simple mechanism for allowing wildcards in data processing operations, it’s often a reasonable solution. But for matching the file names `glob` is the proper way.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're basically asking how to list files in a given directory. What you want is:

```
import os
print os.listdir("""C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\New_folder\export""")
```

If there's multiple files and you want the one(s) that have a .mkv end you could do:

```
import os
files = os.listdir("""C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\New_folder\export""")
mkv_files = [_ for _ in files if _[-4:] == ".mkv"]
print mkv_files
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for recursive folder search, this method will help you to get filename using `os.walk`, also you can get those file's path and directory using this below code.

```
import os, fnmatch
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(r"C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/New_folder/export/")):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, "*.mkv"):
        print(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use glob

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\New_folder\export\*.mkv'):
    print(str(file).split('\')[-1])
```

This will list out all the files having extention .mkv as 
`file.mkv, file2.mkv` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

From *os.walk* you can read file paths as a list

```
files = [ file_path  for _, _, file_path in os.walk(DIRECTORY_PATH)]
for file_name in files[0]: #note that it has list of lists
    print(file_name)
```